# python In conditional while using raw_input (Newbie)

Tags: python, python-2.7, conditional-statements, raw-input

I have a question about using the in `conditional` and `raw_input.`

Basically I am trying to search a dictionary in Python and evaluate the user input. I am trying to check to see if the user input is in the dictionary.

(I won't include the dictionary)

```
shortname=raw_input('Please enter a short name that corresponds to the dictionary: ')

if shortname in paperwork:
    print paperwork['shortname']

else:
    print 'Name Not Found'
```

The issue is when I evaluate the user input, it is declaring it as false when it is actually true. Could anyone help me by telling me what I am doing wrong?

'shortname' in paperwork
False

(What I get when I check manually to see if its valid)

Ive looked around for a bit and I think this question is so basic its not on here. Thanks!

Comment: `'shortname'` and `shortname` are not the same.

Comment: why is that and how do I fix it to get the desired output?

Comment: `'shortname'` is a literal string. `shortname` is a variable. You probably just want to use `shortname` (no quotes) everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your mistake in

```
if shortname in paperwork:
    print paperwork['shortname']
```

Where instead of using the variable `shortname` you are using a String literal `'shortname'`

I don't get any problems in this example I put up:

```
lettersStored = ['a','b','c','d']
name=raw_input('Please enter a letter:\n')

if name in lettersStored:
    print "Found it at index %d " % (lettersStored.index(name))
else:
    print 'Not found'
```

I tested it with inputs:

```
a  (Found it at index 0)
b  (Found it at index 1)
c  (Found it at index 2)
z  (Not Found) 
x  (Not Found)
```

Comment: gah! brackets around if conditional! semicolons at EOL! overwriting builtin `dict` with a *`list`*!

Comment: @nneonneo lol Not a serial python programmer! but I see that by answering questions I also learn about it.

Comment: Yep. It's a good learning experience. One more thing: `myDict` isn't a dictionary. Either define it as one (`{'a':'A', 'b':'B', 'c':'C', 'd':'D'}` or something), or don't call it 'somethingDict'.

Comment: @nneonneo was Calling dictionary not because of the Data Structure but the OO-relation it has with the Question.

Comment: I know, but I'm nitpicking. `dictionary`/`dict` just has a narrower meaning in Python, usually.

Comment: @nneonneo If you know Sauvik Das (Ph.D at CMU) say hi from me :P

Comment: Yes I do. He works in the office opposite mine, we started in the same year. That's a weird coincidence.